# How to re-request URI permission after it is revoked?

Tags: java, android, permissions, uri, android-contentprovider

In my app, I'm opening files from phone storage. I have problems with keeping URI permissions working (*not* with the `EXTERNAL_STORAGE` one).

I first request opening the file as:

```java
Intent mediaIntent = new Intent();
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    mediaIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
} else {
    mediaIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    mediaIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
}
mediaIntent.setType("audio/*");
startActivityForResult(mediaIntent, 1);
```

I am able to get the URI permission and take the "persistable" one as:

```java
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        int takeFlags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
        }
    }
}
```

I am then saving `uri.toString()` in `SharedPreferences` to be able to read the file afterwards. Closing the app or rebooting the phone work fine and I can still access the file. However, if I uninstall the app through `adb uninstall` and then try to access the file afterwards through:

```java
String[] proj = { OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME };
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
```

it turns out that I don't have access to the URI anymore (`checkCallingUriPermission` returns `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED`).

**Is there a way to ask `ContentProvider` to re-grant the URI permissions again after the previous one stopped working?**

Calling:

```
ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
cr.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
```

gives me

```
No persistable permission grants found for UID X and Uri Y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to ask ContentProvider to re-grant the URI permissions again after the previous one stopped working?

No, other than to go back through `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` again, as you did the first time.

Uninstalling the app is designed to leave little behind. From the device's standpoint, your reinstalled app has nothing do to with the original installation of that app.

Also, as [Pawel hints at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55442256/how-to-re-request-uri-permission-after-it-is-revoked-android#comment97600393_55442256), there the question of where your reinstalled app is getting this `Uri`. In principle, while persisting a document `Uri` locally is OK (if you took the persistable permissions), transferring it off-device (backup, your server, etc.) may not work that well.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. Could you repost Pawel's comment? I can't see it (was it deleted?)

Comment: I pulled my comment, but I was wondering if after reinstall You were re-using `uri` that was restored through app backup, which obviously would cause problems.